# Saving Data on Windows Shutdown

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, shutdown

My App (Windows 7, Visual C++, Release-Build) needs to write some data when windows is shutting down (restarting, user logs off). After all I want to do the same stuff as on receiving `WM_CLOSE`-Message which gets called during a regular close of my App (Alt-f4, Closing the window,...)

I don't need any User-Input, Dialogs and so on. Just silent writing. The writing itself should last less than a second.

To do so I do the following:

```
LRESULT CMainFrame::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  if (message == WM_CLOSE){
    TRACE(_T("got WM_CLOSE"));
    SaveMyData();
  }

  switch (message) {
    case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
        TRACE(_T("findme: WM_QUERYENDSESSION"));
        {
                BOOL bShutdownBlocked = ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(theApp.m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), _T("Save data"));
                TRACE(_T("blocked: %d, GetlastError: %d"), bShutdownBlocked, GetLastError());
        }

        //continue shutdown-sequence
        return TRUE;

    case WM_ENDSESSION:
        TRACE(_T("findme: WM_ENDSESSION. Store? %d"), FALSE != (BOOL)wParam);
        if (FALSE != (BOOL)wParam) 
        {
          long lTickStart = GetTickCount();
          TRACE(_T(">>> Sleep..."));
          ::Sleep(1000); //just a Test: do something while shutting down
          TRACE(_T("<<< Sleep: %d ms"), GetTickCount()-lTickStart);

          BOOL bUnblockShutdown = ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(theApp.m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd());
          TRACE(_T("unblock: %d"), bUnblockShutdown);
        }
        return 0L;

    default:
        return CMDIFrameWnd::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

All Traces are redirected into a file which I examine.

I tested this with the Restart Manager from the Logo Testing Tools for Windows under Win7 (`rmtool -S -pid`) and it works fine. I get the following Trace-Output:

```
findme: WM_QUERYENDSESSION
blocked 1, GetlastError: 0
findme: WM_ENDSESSION. Store? 1
>>> Sleep...
<<< Sleep: 1015 ms
unblock: 1
got WM_CLOSE
```

Notice the "got WM_CLOSE" which calls code to save my Data.

But it does not work, when I actually shut windows down or logoff or use `rmtool` with the -lr option. In this case I just get the following output:

```
findme: WM_QUERYENDSESSION
blocked 1, GetlastError: 0
findme: WM_ENDSESSION. Store? 1
>>> Sleep...
<<< Sleep: 1000 ms
unblock: 1
```

Here the `WM_CLOSE`-Message is no received.

Is it wrong to rely on that Message when shutting down or what to I make wrong?

Comment: When shutting down, Windows doesn't send `WM_CLOSE` messages. It does, however, send `WM_ENDSESSION` and `WM_QUIT` messages, so those are what you should be listening for.

Comment: @werner Henze: `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` does not block anything. It just sets a message that gets displayed to the user when shutdown is delayed. The meaning of returning `TRUE` in `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` is "let windows shutdown continue" instead of `FALSE` which would mean "stop shutdown-sequence". And even IF I would return `FALSE` windows still sends `WM_ENDSESSION` but with `wParam` set to 0

Comment: @CodyGray `WM_QUIT` doesn't get sent as well

Comment: It's possible that I misremembered that. You are nevertheless guaranteed to get `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` and `WM_ENDSESSION` in the event of a system shut down. Why don't you just handle one or the other of those?

Comment: @CodyGray <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797625/need-to-access-update-label-value-from-javascript-to-my-code-behind-in-asp-net-c>could you please ans this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trick is do do everything right in `WM_ENDSESSION` without sending or receiving any Windows-Messages.

Also you shouldn't rely too much on the `rmtool.exe`, at least when used without the `-l`-Parameter. It just behaves diffent than shutting down windows. So to test shutdown-scenarios you really have to shutdown (logoff, restart) instead of just simulating it.

Answer (score 1):

As [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shutdown/logging-off) says

> When an application returns TRUE for WM_QUERYENDSESSION, it receives the WM_ENDSESSION message and it is terminated, regardless of how the other applications respond to the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message.

MSDN does not specify that Windows terminates your application by sending a `WM_CLOSE` to it. You should do the saving in the `WM_ENDSESSION` handler to be on the safe side.

BTW, you should remove the call to `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`. What is the use of it? If it worked you would not get a `WM_ENDSESSION` anymore. That function should be called in advance if you want to prevent a shutdown.

Comment: ShutdownBlockReasonCreate is OK. See MSDN : _Applications should call this function as they begin an operation that cannot be interrupted, such as burning a CD or DVD. When the operation has completed, call the ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy function to indicate that the system can be shut down._

Comment: @Castorix If you call `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` in the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` handler, what do you expect? The code shown expects a `WM_ENDSESSION`. Case 1: Windows is already doing a shutdown (thus the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`) and ignores `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` -> so why call the function? Case 2: Windows is accepting the `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`, so it will not proceed and `WM_ENDSESSION` will not be sent, thus `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy` will not be called and the `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` will stay in effect until the application is closed. Both cases don't look right to me.

Comment: @WernerHenze: see my comment above (was originally to your first comment which is deleted meanwhile). `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` dooesn't blocks anything. It just sets a User-Message

Comment: And if you see MS samples (old SDK) (or adapted samples on Github) ShutdownBlockReasonCreate is always called in   WM_QUERYENDSESSION, just to inform Windows

Comment: @Castorix [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate) says "Indicates that the system cannot be shut down and sets a reason string to be displayed to the user if system shutdown is initiated.". From my understanding `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` is sent *after* system shutdown is initiated. So I fail to see why `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` in `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` should work. I can't find a good documentation for it, so maybe I should just write a short program to test it.

Comment: @Castorix [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/Shutdown/shutting-down): applications block shutdown if they return `FALSE` in `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`. They should not do so. If they do, then `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` gives a reason to the user. This page does not argue to call `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` if you do not block shutdown.